# On vagrant box, FOSUserBundle login form just reloads - but other forms work

Tags: php, apache, symfony, vagrant, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to get my Symfony app up using a vagrant box (centos and apache2) and I seem to have an issue with FOSUserBundle logging in.

When I view the login page, everything renders properly:
[image: screen shot 2015-05-11 at 2 11 00 pm]

But when I try to login, it just reloads the page -- no error. Errors typically display on these page (database connection, wrong credentials). You'll notice that it makes a request to login_check/ and then gets a 302 which pushes it to login/ again:
[image: screen shot 2015-05-11 at 2 12 14 pm]

So, I know this works on my Windows machine on WAMP and my production machine on CentOs, so I figured there was something wrong with my vagrant box. So I did a completely different box, this time using ubuntu and nginx and encountered the same issue.

I have looked through:
- app/prod.log
- /var/log/httpd
- app/dev.log
and I do not see any errors. It's just as if FOSUserBundle is sending the post data into login_check and then immediately just redirecting back to login.

Here is a screenshot of the only thing I can get out of the dev.log:
[image: screen shot 2015-05-11 at 2 10 09 pm]

config.yml:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: Shawmut\ClientBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
            form:
                type: shawmut_user_registration
    profile:
            form:
                type: shawmut_user_profile
```

security.yaml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

Oddly enough, other forms work. The forgot password page which comes with FOSUserBundle seems to be executing properly.

Anyone have any idea of what the problem could be or what steps I could take to troubleshoot?

**Edit:**
Ran phpunit on my FOSUserBundle and was able to encounter this fatal error. Not sure if it is related:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/689

> My problem was with the session handler in the app/config/config.yml,
>   try with this:

```
...
framework:
...
    session:
        handler_id: ~ 
...
```

Adding "handler_id: ~" to "session:" fixed my issue.